# How to know which system calls are generated by library calls in a program using gdb?

Tags: linux, bash, gdb, system-calls

I am currently  running gdb with the following specifications:

```
gdb ./executable
tui enable
layout asm
catch syscall
break main
run
stepi
c
```

And I get output such as the following:

> Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall write), 0x00007ffff7af4154 in __GI___libc_write (fd=2,
>   Contbuf=0x7ffffffebd80, nbytes=66) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c:27

And it highlights this in the tui:

> │0x7ffff7af4154 <__GI___libc_write+20>   cmp    $0xfffffffffffff000,%rax

I am not completely sure how to read this - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `how to read this` read "this" - what exactly?

Comment: I'm looking for library calls from the system calls using the gdb, so I'm unsure how to read the assembly code from gdb.